# How to quickly find a property of WinForms control?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, resharper

Recently I started a project in WinForms. I'm coming from WPF background and I find some things new to me. For example every time I want to change a property of WinForms control I have to scroll up and down to find it.

It drives me mad. I would rather type first few letters of looked up property and edit it in a couple of seconds. Is there a way to speed up this annoying process?

[image: hate it]

Comment: Resizing your properties window?

Comment: Click on `Alphabetical` button on the property grid toolbar. This way at least properties will show in alphabetical order.

Comment: To your specific question:  no, you can't.  Alphabetizing might help some, but if you want "Visible", you're going to have to scroll down to it.

Comment: You could set your property directly in the code, this way you won't have to scroll in the property bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to filter properties of control. I know how you feel, as I switch between WPF and WinForms from project to project. But you can always either Categorize them or sort them alphabetically... I am sure you'll get used to it eventually, but you have to understand though, Windows Forms are not as "innovative" as WPF is. Therefore you'll see some things are rather more "traditional" than WPF in WinForms! Sorry mate :)

[image: Visual studio 2015 properties window]

Answer (score 0):

There is a VS Extension called RapidDesign. It is a payed project but I think it's worth the price. It does exactly what you need and even more. (Note!!! I am not connected in anyway with the author/company that develops this product)

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c820e3a0-add2-4a43-943c-029e296ab00d

You can download the extension directly from VisualStudio galery or you can install it from inside VS by going to Tools->Extensions And Updates...->Online->and search for RapidDesign

Comment: If anyone comes across this extension DO NOT BUY IT!!!  The trial is great and the site still accepts payment, but when I tried to buy a license the site failed and all the contact/support forms are broken.